# Old giant robot movie where an (ejected) pilot fires a discarded robot fist by connecting wires

Tags: story-identification, robots, mecha

I saw it very early in my childhood, between about 20-25 years ago.

- Live action
- People were piloting giant robots (can't remember just how big)
- I believe they were moving their feet and hands while being in upright position to control the robot (similar to Pacific Rim)
- People on the streets had the surgical white masks (China or Japan probably)
- I think the robots were fighting it out in arenas, but not sure about this part

There was a robot that would fire its own fists as a projectile. The protagonist pilot ended up on the ground outside his robot (I believe it was destroyed/damaged). He hid behind one of these discarded previously fired fists. He then tinkered with the exposed wires from the robot fist and finally managed to active it. The fist either flew at the (bad) robot, or it fired some missiles at it.

I don't even know in what language the movie was...

Thank you

Comment: Was it a live action or animation movie?

Comment: @Kreiri it was live action

Comment: I have an original movie poster of this one!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like [**Robot Jox**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Jox) (1990). I'm fairly certain the scene in question is during the final battle between Achilles and Alexander, but I haven't been able to find it on YouTube.

> The film's plot follows Achilles, one of the "robot jox" who pilot
>   giant mechanical machines that fight international battles to settle
>   territorial disputes in a dystopian post-apocalyptic world.

Here's the first fight between the two, which does indeed take place inside an arena:

...and here is the fight scene with the rocket fist:

Comment: That's it! Wow, it actually doesn't look so bad even now.