# Old giant robot movie where the protagonist won the battle and saved himself using the robot's rocket fist

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I read [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84059/old-giant-robot-movie-where-an-ejected-pilot-fires-a-discarded-robot-fist-by-c) to another movie identification question and the description was so similar to a movie I'm looking for that I thought it was the same one, but it's not.

The movie I'm looking for also features an old giant robot with a rocket fist and it also was shown about 25 years ago in the cinema, but I can barely remember the final scene in which the pilot fires his robot's arm and then his robot explodes. For a while, it appeared that he was dead, then the camera revealed that he used a trick and stayed alive in the rocket fist.

UPD 01.

- It is the live action film with old SFX
- I saw it in Russia, but - i believe - it was filmed elsewhere
- It is not "Robot Jox" or "Robot Wars", i checked
- My bad explanation. Protagonist was in robot at the fist launching moment. Fist was connected to a robot before launch. After the launch robot was destroyed (not sure) and the pilot appeared to be alive inside this fist. That i called 'trick'.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where was it you saw this?  (What country?)  I assume it was animated; do you remember the animation style?

Comment: could it be Robot Wars? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypvoUEGuW8c not sure if this got a cinema release and its maybe older than you mention. Never watched the whole thing myself but stuff like the old piloted robot certainly fits.

Comment: Maybe Robot Jox from 1990?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Jox  Fist-launching is a plot point in several parts of the movie, but I don't recall the specific twist of the pilot staying alive inside the fist specifically.

Comment: This also reminds me of the film Big Hero 6, which ended with the robot Baymax releasing his rocket fist to propel his friends home from a parallel dimension. Baymax also put his brain chip into the fist so that he could later be rebuilt. This movie only came out about ten years ago, though.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thank you all and please see the upd-01.

Comment: Yes the first thing i thought was Big Hero 6 too, but apparently it's been done before.

Comment: Crash and Burn 1990? It does not have the trick scene but theres a ejecting robot arm, the movie was marketed as robotjox 2